# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' Flutter

Tags: json, string, flutter, dart

I am working on creating a data table from JSON response in Flutter.
Currently, I am stuck on a particular error that is stated as the heading of this post.
I'm not sure what is wrong so I'm asking for your help.
This is the code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:json_table/json_table.dart';

class API extends StatefulWidget {
  final File slika;
  final String response;
  API({Key key, this.slika, this.response}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _APIState createState() => _APIState();
}

class _APIState extends State<API> {
  var user;
  int rowLength = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonDecode(widget.response)['rows'].length; i++) {
      if (jsonDecode(widget.response)['rows'][i].length > rowLength) {
        rowLength = jsonDecode(widget.response)['rows'][i].length;
      }
    }
    print(widget.response);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF48494D),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
              child: JsonTable(
            jsonDecode(widget.response),
            tableHeaderBuilder: (String header) {
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 0.5), color: Colors.grey[300]),
                child: Text(
                  header,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1.copyWith(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      color: Colors.black87),
                ),
              );
            },
            tableCellBuilder: (value) {
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0, vertical: 2.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5))),
                child: Text(
                  value,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .display1
                      .copyWith(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.grey[900]),
                ),
              );
            },
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I used json_table widget library for Flutter, so the end result should look something like this for reference:
[image]

Thank You very much for your help.

Comment: What is the line that triggers this error ?

Comment: "jsonDecode(widget.response),"

Comment: For efficiency, you should probably do the `json.decode` in the constructor of the widget or in `didUpdateWidget` of the state. Doing it each `build` (in fact several times per build) is unnecessary. Does your json decode to a list rather than a map? Update the question to show at least the start of the json.

Comment: This is the JSON resposne, after decoding: [{"Iznos s PDV": "625,00","%PDV": "Iznos PDV","bez PDV": "bez PDV","Cijena": "Iznos","BBK": "Yorabata","JMJ": "KOM","Koli\u010dina": "1,00","Naziv artikla": "BA\u010cVA 30L","Artikl": "FAN kod","Rbr.": "1"},{"Iznos s PDV": "625,00.","%PDV": "25,00%","bez PDV": "500,00","Cijena": " ","BBK": "500,00","JMJ": " ","Koli\u010dina": " ","Naziv artikla": " ","Artikl": "9999800","Rbr.": " "}]

Comment: On the code that you shared the `index` variable, which is the source of the error, is not visible. Can you share the code?

Comment: That is the full code of this page, I am not transferring any index variable from the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone with the same problem, the solution was to change the variable type of the Header variable. This is because Dart can't reverse integer to String by itself.
By changing this:

```
tableHeaderBuilder: (String header) {
```

to this:

```
tableHeaderBuilder: (header) {
```

You solved the problem!